# Saving to database in Grails

Tags: java, grails

This is my domain:

```
class UserFeedBack 
{
    int rating1
    int rating2
    int rating3
    int rating4
    int rating5
}
```

This is my controller:

```
def addResponse(params)
{
    UserFeedBack feedback_response = new UserFeedBack()
    def answer =JSON.parse(params.answer)//this comes from ajax
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
       if(feedback_response.rating+i!="")
       {
            feedback_response.rating+i=answer.rating+i.toInteger()
       }
    }
}
```

This is a compile time error.
Isn't there any way similar to save to database?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){    
    if(feedback_response['rating'+i]){    
        feedback_response['rating'+i] = (answer['rating'+i] as Integer)

        feedback_response.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

If you want to access the property of an object by dynamically created name, you need to use `[]`. And remember `"rating"` is String and needs to be in parentheses.

You can also omit `!=""` in `if` clause, because empty string is [`falsy`](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_strings) value.

To persist an object to the database, you need to call `save`.